# switching between ARM/THUMB state

Tags: arm

Why should an ARM controller return to ARM state from THUMB state, when an exception occurs?

Comment: It depends which CPU you have, as there are two thumb instruction sets. The original thumb instruction set (used in armv4t, armv5te) lacked instructions to be able to deal with interrupts; .... Do you know what are the instructions lacked by armv4t or armv5te to deal with interrupts?
Thanks for your kindly reply.

Answer (score 6):

One explanation might be that ARM mode is the CPU's "native" operating mode, and that it's possible to do more operations in that mode than in the limited Thumb mode. The Thumb mode, as far as I've understood, is optimized for code size, which might mean it lacks certain instructions that perhaps are necessary in exception processing.

[This page](http://books.google.se/books?id=J_Fu_YTVD9gC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=arm+exit+thumb+exception&source=bl&ots=DjELg3TCnl&sig=CamX3f4p2fjJYRBPOmTXgBeQbmQ&hl=en&ei=Wy3TSpjvPNzOjAf27b2DBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CA0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=arm%20exit%20thumb%20exception&f=false) mentions that exception processing is always done in ARM mode. It doesn't provide any reasons why, so maybe it's just The Way It Is, by design. It does talk about ways to exit from exception processing back to the proper (ARM or Thumb) mode though, so as long as you're not writing the exception handler yourself, you might be able to ignore this issue. That, of course, assumes that your system is set up with a "default" exception handler that does retain the execution mode.

On the other hand, [this page](http://books.google.se/books?id=T9heqSaErCcC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=arm+exit+thumb+exception&source=bl&ots=eNtvy9Hh7u&sig=sAnY3Cnv4yWA468hOPTSPN_tErY&hl=en&ei=Wy3TSpjvPNzOjAf27b2DBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=12&ved=0CDUQ6AEwCw#v=snippet&q=thumb%20exception&f=false) says this, about the interrupt vectors of the Cortex-M3 ARM implementation:

> The LSB of each exception vector indicates whether the exception is to
>   be executed in the Thumb state.

So it doesn't seem to be universally true, perhaps you can make your particular exception run in Thumb mode.

Comment: That thing about the LSB is basically correct. A branch ends up in ARM mode if the LSB is clear, and Thumb if it's set. This is also why Thumb function pointers seem "out of alignment". I should know - I spent the better part of today in IDA.

Comment: That's only true if you have interworking enabled; watch out for bugs where you didn't set your compiler flags correctly!

Comment: Cortex M3 has only Thumb2 mode, ARM mode is not available there. The exception model is very different from traditional ARM model.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is because that the interrupt vector table is really an ARM instruction and to process it requires being in ARM mode.  This reduces the programmers job as you dont have to write two handlers one for arm mode and one for thumb mode.  How would you even know there is one entry point for an exception and you can only have one instruction type to handle it.  You can certainly switch to thumb mode once entered no different than switching to thumb mode after a reset exception.

The cortex-m3 has re-defined the interrupt vector table to be more traditional (an address instead of an instruction).  By necessity I would assume, the cortex-m3 is a thumb(2) only processor so either they re-define the vector table to hold thumb instructions or they re-define the table with addresses, or they have just enough of an arm core to process the load or jump that you normally see in a vector table entry.

Basically you would either need two entries per exception, one for the arm based handler and one for the thumb based handler or you require the user to write their handler with an entry point that is one mode specifically.

Even with the one mode entry point into a handler, you still have to be aware of the mode the processor was in when the exception occurred to know what address to return to and how to inspect the instruction in question that caused the exception.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which CPU you have, as there are two thumb instruction sets. The original thumb instruction set (used in armv4t, armv5te) lacked instructions to be able to deal with interrupts; the newer thumb2 set (in the cortex series) has extra instructions so you can remain in thumb2 mode to service an interrupt routine.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional ARM systems boot into ARM mode and jumps to reset exception vector after reset. This means that all exception vectors have to be written in ARM assembly. If your exceptions are ARM instructions naturally the CPU is forced to change its mode to ARM mode before exception handling; if this does not happen it will result in an undefined exception, which will cause another one and so on and on in an infinite loop.

Initial ARM systems only had ARM instructions, the THUMB instructions were later added on; this might be another explanation.